# Another generic MySQL error w/ PHP PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm getting MySQL error 42000:1064 that suggests a general syntax error with the following SQL:

```
UPDATE `events` SET ?=?, ?=?, ?=now() WHERE `event_id`=?;
```

PHP code to convert to a readable statement & also execute:

```
<?php
$ar = array_fill(0,count($args),'/\?/');
echo preg_replace($ar,$args,$sql,1);
$this->execute($sql, $args);
?>
```

This evaluates to:

```
    UPDATE `events` SET event_name=test, form_id=webform, last_updated=now() WHERE `event_id`=124;
```

Which when  pasted into the MySQL workbench completes successfully.

```
[mysqlErrorMsg] => SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''event_name'='test', 'form_id'='webform', 'last_updated'=now() WHERE `event_id`=' at line 1
```

*It should be noted that my user has full access to the table in question.*

Comment: You can't use placeholders on column names. Only on values

Comment: @juergend I wrote the same thing then deleted it. He's not using prepared statements, he's using `preg_replace` to substitute the placeholders.

Comment: I hope he doesn't use any question marks inside strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use placeholders on column names. Only on values.

Your query does NOT evaluate to (as it should)

```
UPDATE `events` SET event_name=test, form_id=webform, last_updated=now()
WHERE `event_id`=124;
```

but is being evaluated as this instead:

```
UPDATE `events` SET 'event_name'='test', 'form_id'='webform', 'last_updated'=now() 
WHERE `event_id`=124;
```

See the quotes? These are strings, not column names.

So hard code the column names and only use placeholders for values

```
UPDATE `events` SET event_name=?, form_id=?, last_updated=now() WHERE `event_id`=?;
```

Comment: You can't put single quotes around column names, they should be backquotes.

Comment: Looks I explained it not that good. That is exactly my point in the answer

Comment: @Barmar the quotes are placed there by the PDO engine. Juergen is right, I can't use PDO to define the keys. I'll accept the answer in a few minutes when SO allows.